# Serialise to YAML using XStream in Java

Tags: java, yaml, xstream

**Is there a YAML driver for the Java [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/) package?**

I'm already using XStream to serialise/deserialise both XML and JSON. I'd like to be able to do the same with YAML.

Comment: "Serialise" is the correct British spelling. Either the British or American spelling would be acceptable, but I don't think it should be "corrected" from whatever the OP chooses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse a YAML document you can use this chain:
YAML -> SnakeYAML -> Java -> Your Application (-> XStream -> XML)

Emitting YAML is simpler and there are a couple of options:
1) Your Application -> XStream with Custom Writer -> YAML
2) Your Application -> SnakeYAML -> YAML

The second option does not require any additional development.

Answer (score 1):

You might find that helpful to get a direction: [XStream - how to serialize objects to non XML formats](http://joe.truemesh.com/blog//000479.html)

Answer (score 0):

I used JYAML and it worked great.  I know it doesn't directly answer your question but it works well.

Answer (score 0):

While XStream is pretty nice for XML, JSON it produces is rather ugly, due to conversion using Badgerfish notation.

But you could consider using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) for all 3; since while the default package just handles JSON, there are extensions for both [XML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) and [YAML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml), and all work using same powerful data-binding functionality, just differ on low-level parsers and generators (for XML, Stax API is used)